After successful SSH connections can not type anything
I am using Ubuntu and after my successful login in my SSH I can not type anything. When I reboot my computer and open a Terminal, I run the command ssh root@****. I receive a password prompt where I enter the correct password, showing me the welcome message . After that instead of receiving the prompt, I have a blinking cursor on a new line and I can not type anything.Yesterday everything was working well and now I am facing this problem.
I have also tried creating a new user but it is all the same.
In the image I have deleted the files with the pass and the shh root login(safety reasons).
this is the problem that I am facing
Here are my SSHD logs
May 9 11:04:44 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New seat seat0.
May 9 11:04:49 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD useradd[1042]: new user: name=lxd, UID=998, GID=100, home=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd, shell=/bin/false, from=none
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1324]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New session 1 of user
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1568]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New session 3 of user root.
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1637]: ROOT LOGIN on '/dev/pts/3'
May 9 11:17:01 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD CRON[1890]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:17:01 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD CRON[1890]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:23:22 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
May 9 11:23:22 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:23:50 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart sshd
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:25:41 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl list-unit-files
May 9 11:25:41 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:25:42 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start ssh.service
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status ssh.service
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:41:35 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[296]: New seat seat0.
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[549]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[296]: New session 1 of user user
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:41:44 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[782]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)


It's probably due to your internet connection, same used to happen to me. also, enclose the terminal output in code identifiers please

This can be a symptom of a long-running (or recursive) command in the user's (in this case, root's) shell startup file(s) - for example, sourcing /root/.bashrc from /root/.profile and then sourcing /root/.profile from /root/.bashrc

/root/.bashrc from /root/.profile and then sourcing /root/.profile from /root/.bashrc how can I solve this?

@Amirreza my internet connection is fine. I really don't  know what to do next

Please format logs and output from the terminal as code using the {_} icon above the edit question window in the future.
